Formulation of multipoint constraints using Lagrange multipliers for a time dependent problem (with the Finite Element Method)
Intro
Suppose we have the following static linear equations (e.g. of an elastostatic problem):
$$\mathbf{K}\boldsymbol{u}=\boldsymbol{f}$$
We want a multipoint constraint of the type
$$\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{q}=\boldsymbol{0}$$
In all FEM textbooks I have read (Hughes, Zienkiewicz, Cook, Bath, among others) I could only find this sort of constraint applied for static problems.
Using Lagrange multipliers $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$, we now define a "discrete energy functional" $\Pi$ such that
$$\Pi = \frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{u}^\intercal\mathbf{K}\boldsymbol{u} - \boldsymbol{u}^\intercal\boldsymbol{f}-\boldsymbol{\lambda}^\intercal\left(\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{q}\right)$$
Then we search for the values of $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ that minimize $\Pi$, so $\frac{\partial\Pi}{\partial\boldsymbol{u}}=\boldsymbol{0}$ and $\frac{\partial\Pi}{\partial\boldsymbol{\lambda}}=\boldsymbol{0}$ yielding:
$$\left[\matrix{\mathbf{K} & \boldsymbol{\Lambda}^\intercal \cr \boldsymbol{\Lambda} & \boldsymbol{0}}\right] \left[ \matrix{\boldsymbol{u} \cr \boldsymbol{\lambda}} \right] = \left[ \matrix{\boldsymbol{f} \cr \boldsymbol{q}} \right]$$
Problem
How do I formulate this for the transient problem?
Namely, for the following linear system:
$$ \mathbf{M}\ddot{\boldsymbol{u}} + \mathbf{C}\dot{\boldsymbol{u}} + \mathbf{K}\boldsymbol{u} = \boldsymbol{f} $$
Let's say the constraints are:
$$\boldsymbol{r}_1 = \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_1 \boldsymbol{u} - \boldsymbol{q}_1 = \boldsymbol{0}$$
$$ \boldsymbol{r}_2 = \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_2 \dot{\boldsymbol{u}} - \boldsymbol{q}_2 = \boldsymbol{0}$$
$$ \boldsymbol{r}_3 = \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_3 (\boldsymbol{u}-\dot{\boldsymbol{u}}) - \boldsymbol{q}_3 = \boldsymbol{0}$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_1$, $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_2$ and $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_3$ constrain disjointed sets of degrees of freedom.
What is the constrained equation? What functional (Lagrangian, Hamiltonian...) describes this problem?
Assume $\mathbf{M}$, $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ are symmetric.
Carpenter et. al. [1] formulated this for the contact problem, without using a variational principle. Additionally, they only use Lagrange multiplers for $\boldsymbol{u}$, but not for $\dot{\boldsymbol{u}}$. I think it's because of the hypothesis that "internal forces are strain-rate independent and proportional to displacement", for small displacements. Or maybe because the surface-contact problem only requires a coupling on $\boldsymbol{u}$, but not on $\dot{\boldsymbol{u}}$? In anycase, shouldn't a multipoint constraint on some degrees of freedom also imply a similar constraint on their time derivatives? From what I understood of Hetherington et. al. [2], apparently we can constrain both the stiffness and the inertia independently, which is confusing to me.
This question is different from How to apply Lagrange Multipliers to BCs of Time Dependent problems using finite elements? because I am interested in the mathematical formulation of this problem.
References
1 N. J. Carpenter, R. L. Taylor and M. G. Katona (1991) Lagrange constraints for transient finite element surface contact. Int. J. Numer. Meth. Engng., 32: 103-128. DOI: 10.1002/nme.1620320107
2 J. Hetherington, A. Rodríguez-Ferran and H. Askes (2013) The bipenalty method for arbitrary multipoint constraints. Int. J. Numer. Meth. Engng, 93: 465-482. DOI: 10.1002/nme.4389
